# Nginx `auth_request` vs Nodejs Authentication Middleware

Tags: node.js, authentication, nginx, jwt, auth-request

I have a *NodeJS* Restful API server which is publicly accessible to consume *Rest API Services*. I have `JWT` authentication implementation in place as middleware method when any request comes in to access secure end-point. These services are exposed publicly via an *Nginx Reverse-proxy* server.

Recently, I just came across *Nginx* `auth_request` technique to authenticate the request which seems pretty nice concept in different ways where we can use it as in *Nginx* sub-request i.e. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/

After looking at *Nginx* sub-request mechanism it seems really handy to use with existing *NodeJS* (or any other API services) app, or we can also use any other explicit authentication service to authenticate the request.

The only things that I am confused with and really want to understand are:

- Is there any specific use-case where we can use *Nginx* approach over *NodeJS* middleware?
- What would be the difference in terms of security point
- What would be the performance impact when there are hundreds of users accessing same *NodeJS* (protected) API services. I mean which approach will give us what sort of benefit or limitation
- Any difference in terms of future scalability

Looking forward to hear from relevant experts who can better understand my problem statement and can advise or share their understanding and assessment.